# How can I generate expected values of normal order statistics with different n in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics

Is there an embedded function in MATLAB that I can use to generate expected values of normal order statistics with n from 1 to 1000?

Or does anyone know if there is a thrid-party algorithm for that?

Any suggestion will be helpful!

Comment: There is a `rankits.m` function for that in http://www.faculty.biol.ttu.edu/Strauss/Matlab/Matlab.htm (Strauss, R. E., "Matlab statistical functions"). Hope its a start.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this question is well posed.

But if you made a vector using linspace(a,b,step)

```
vector = linspace(1,1000,n);
```

then you could get the expectation using

```
expectation = sum(vector)/n;
```

But this is just an average since the probability of each point is unknown